# Search for key in nested Python dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to search for key-value pairs in Python dict. My dict is nested, so simple solution like:

```
if 'keyname' in my_dict:
...
```

or:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if 'keyname' == key:
```

does not work for me.
This is my dict:

```
my_dict = {'a': 111,
           'b': 222,
           'c':{'d': 333,
                'e': 444},
           'f':555,
           'g':{'h': {'i': 666}}}
```

And I want to find value of 'i' or 'd', whats the simplest way to do that?
I do not care for name of the key that has nested dict. For example, I do not care for key name of 'c' or 'g' or 'h', I only care about key-values (key-number).
Is there a way to transform my dict to look like this:

```
my_result = {'a': 111,
             'b': 222,
             'd': 333,
             'e': 444,
             'f': 555,
             'i': 666}
```

In that way it would be easy.

Comment: Things to think about here: 1) Is there any chance of a key appearing more than once, say nested under two different higher level keys? 2) Your example contains only integers and dicts as values. Is that something you can count on always being true? 3) You propose flattening the dictionary. Do you anticipate searching for multiple keys over the same dict, or just one or two? That helps determine whether the processing time to flatten is worthwhile or whether you should just recursively search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the dictionary using recursion here.

```py
def flat(data):
    out = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            out.update(flat(v))
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out

flat(my_dict)
# {'a': 111, 'b': 222, 'd': 333, 'e': 444, 'f': 555, 'i': 666}
```

Comment: And what if I have list instead of nested dict. So I have a dict that has list of dicts as value?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
def find_value(_key, _dict):
    for key, value in list(_dict.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result = find_value(_key, value)
            if result:
                return result
        if key == _key:
            return value
```